# How can I use .replace to change a url structure from this+word to this-word?

Tags: javascript, magento, url

I'm going nuts trying to figure out how to replace a querystring url in Magento from using the + sign to using a dash (-) between words.  I purchased an awesome extension from fishpig:http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/seo-search-urls/

But I have not been able to get it to work.  Ben (the code) has been working with me to try to get the functionality going, but I'm trying to be a bit proactive.

It seems to me that the problem lies in a .replace section in his code.

```
                var value = fld.getValue()
                .toLowerCase()
                    .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
                        .replace('  ', ' ');
```

All my search urls still have /this+word/ instead of /this-word/  but I don't see where in the .replace the change from the + to the - dash should occur.

Comment: `.replace(/\+/g, '-')` You need the `g`lobal modifier to replace all `+` with `-`.

Comment: Where in the code would you add or change this.  I've tried several different ways but so far, still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape + with backslash

```
var string="some+thing+in+my+closet";
alert(string.replace(/\+/g,"-"));
```